# How to configure Mtail with NginX and prometheus

Tags: docker, nginx, logging, monitoring

I wanted to monitor my nginx access logs(mainly the time taken by each route) and I came to know that Mtail is a good service for that. I am already using prometheus to monitor the status of my requests. How do I use mtail and connect it between the nginx logs and prometheus.

Note: I do not know any basics of Go. Implementation using Docker would be helpful.

In the Mtail docs, I could see that they are providing release binaries. But, I do not know how to use them and initiate Mtail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I made a generic [Ansible Role to install Prometheus exporters](https://github.com/Lusitaniae/ansible-role-prometheus-exporter-installer/), while mtail is not built the same way, the installation is basically the same.

First, you need to amend `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, and update the log_format and log_access directives.

```
log_format mtail '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                  '"$request" $status $bytes_sent $request_time'
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /jet/log/nginx/access.log mtail;
```

Then you need to install mtail

```
# create dir
mkdir -p /etc/mtail

# download mtail
wget https://github.com/google/mtail/releases/download/v3.0.0-rc33/mtail_v3.0.0-rc33_linux_amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/mtail

# make it executable
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mtail

# install mtail config file
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipfs/infra/master/mtail/progs/nginx.mtail -O /etc/mtail/nginx.mtail
```

Test mtail using

```
./mtail  --logs /var/log/nginx/access.log  --progs /etc/mtail/

curl localhost:3903 -s | grep title
    <title>mtail on :3903</title>
```

Create unprivileged user

```
useradd -r exporter
```

and finally install mtail as a service (systemd)

create `/etc/systemd/system/mtail.service` with the followig content

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus mtail
User=exporter
Group=exporter
After=local-fs.target network-online.target network.target
Wants=local-fs.target network-online.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mtail --logs /var/log/nginx/access.log  --progs /etc/mtail/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And enable / start it

```
systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl enable mtail.service

systemctl start mtail.service
```